# Want to create new Cms page which have a contats forms.How will i do

Tags: cms, contact-us

please visit this links : http://www.gasandplumbingsupplies.co.nz/contactus

http://www.gasandplumbingsupplies.co.nz/gallery/Mixers/aquatica-sink-mixer/question/314445

I wanted to do both pages in magento.

first link is "contact us", that's no problem.

How to create second link "Ask a question".?....

I am plannig to create CMS page - > "Ask a question"

how to create second links page in magento?

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you want to show contact us form to ask question page?

Comment: thanks a lot for reply, no, i need both "contact us" and " ASk question " page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this `by update layout of Ask question page using contact us page layout.`

GOTO `admin>CMS>Page>`

Create Cms page then `goto it Design > add below code to Layout Update XML` e and make replicate of contacts/form.phtml name abform.phtml

```
     <reference name="content">
      <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/abform.phtml">
  </block>
    </reference>
```

and `abform.phtml` form action should be `Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post')`

Comment: hi, I created cms page "abform" , and added the above code in Design > layout update update xml. as i am new to magento,  i did't got the last  line : "and abform.phtml form action should be Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post')"

Comment: hi, i changed Mage::helper('contacts') to => Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post') in abform.phtml. am i did what you told?

Comment: please visit this link : http://gas1.newtrendzonline.com/abform

Comment: currently template hint is enabled,please disable it

Comment: can give 29 line no codes thus i will check

Comment: please check abform.phtml http://pastebin.com/E143m14n

Comment: remove  all  Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post') using  Mage::helper('contacts')

Comment: $this->getFormAction();  replace by  Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post')

Comment: i have check form action is not set please replace $this->getFormAction();  by Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post')

Comment: http://gas1.newtrendzonline.com/abform . you are just amazing.... wonderfull.... thanks a lot....